# keyboardWillShow events make additional changes

Tags: ios

I have a chat view and I transition the textView up with the keyboard by changing the height of the view.  However, when I change the keyboard type to emoji, and also back to regular keyboard, the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification fires again and move the view an additional step up (ie an additional height of the keyboard).
How can I keep track of this and make sure I only subtract the height of a keyboard if it is not already subtracted, or only subtract the additional height of the emoji keyboard ?

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        self.view.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height - keyboardSize.height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

[image]

> I change keyboard to emoji

[image]

> I change keyboard from emoji and back to normal

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using self.view.frame.height, use screen height.

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
    self.view.frame.size.height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height - keyboardSize.height
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

}

An even more simpler way is to import this third party utility in your code

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

It automatically handles everything you want.